# Color edges and vertex in chord diagram using edgebundle

Tags: r

I am trying to make a chord diagram, where vertex are grouped by a factor (modules) and edges are colored by other factor.

I really like the layout achieved when using the `edgebundle()` and I tried to follow all the directions from here:

> [Network chord diagram woes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r/32260962)

(He describes a "hacking" method to color the edges, but I can't manages to do that...) 
So, I cannot find a way to implement these two coloring rules in any easy way.

So I am thinking of now abandon the `edgebundle()` and start over using a function like `chordDiagram()` - But I really like the layout better in the first function (plus I spend soo much time already on this)
Maybe someone can help me and I can stick with the `edgebundle()`.

Here is my steps - It is not pretty, I apologize, I am not very skilled in R, so I do things is stupid ways often.

The `consensus_taxa` is a data frame of the edges, where the labels for taxa1 and taxa2 includes a prefix of the module number it belongs to, like this:

```
                             taxa1                              taxa2        rho
1  3.ITS_Uncl.Mortierella_OTU985144    3.ITS_Uncl.Ascomycota_OTU258690 -0.9725180
2     1.ITS_Uncl.Mortierella_OTU979  1.ITS_Uncl.Mortierella_OTU2523736  0.9629500
3    3.ITS_Uncl.Pleosporales_OTU136349 3.ITS_Uncl.Basidiomycota_OTU258716  0.9615385
```

And the `m_meta` is meta data, such as additional labels and again the module information:

```
m_meta[1:3,1:7]
                                  comb                           taxa1    trt        rho module
1  1.Bact_Uncl.Proteobacteria_OTU248 Bact_Uncl.Proteobacteria_OTU248 meadow -0.5000000      1
2   1.Bact_Uncl.Bacteroidetes_OTU695  Bact_Uncl.Bacteroidetes_OTU695 meadow -0.8434475      1
3  1.ITS_Uncl.Mortierella_OTU2523736 ITS_Uncl.Mortierella_OTU2523736 meadow  0.9629500      1
                      ID  Org
1    Uncl.Proteobacteria Bact
2      Uncl.Bacteroidetes Bact
3       Uncl.Mortierella  ITS
```

So here is my attempt:

```
g_my <- graph.data.frame(consensus_taxa, directed=F, vertices=m_meta)
  mod_col <- as.factor(as.character(V(g_my)$module))
  # generation random colors
  cl <- colors(distinct = TRUE)
  set.seed(15887) # to set random generator seed
  mycols2 <- sample(cl, length(levels(mod_col)))
  levels(mod_col) <- as.character(mycols2)
  V(g_my)$color <- as.character(mod_col)

  # Edge color green when positiv (rho >0) and red when negativ
  edge_col <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=1)
  for (i in 1:length(consensus_taxa$rho)){
    t <- consensus_taxa$rho[i]
    ecol <- if(t>0) {as.character("green")} else {as.character("red")}
  edge_col <- rbind(edge_col, ecol)
  print(i/length(consensus_taxa$rho)) }
  E(g_my)$color <- as.character(edge_col)

  v_lab <- as.character(m_meta$ID)

  #### Loosing sorting of the vertex in the circle (and in the general the  layout is fare from nice)
   plot(g_my, layout = layout.circle, vertex.size=degree(g_my)*0.5, vertex.label = v_lab)

   #### loosing color codes and labels in this way, but layout is in general nice
   edgebundle(g_my)->eb
  eb
```

Any suggestions?

Here is how it looks (there is a size issue also in the first one).

```
[![edgebundle][1]][1]
[![normal_plot][2]][2]
[![no_labels][3]][3]
```

Comment: Sorry, the upload of the images of the plots did not work (At least I don't see them).

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)