# Chord diagram with barplots - how can I reproduce it in R

Tags: r, plot, chord-diagram

SO is giving me a hint that questions with similar titles have frequently been closed, but I cannot find an answer. Lately I have seen the following diagram on Bloomberg a lot, especially in representing Import/Export volumes:

[image]

Is it possible to get something like this in R? If yes, what package is used?

*As soon as I figure out the name of the plot I will update the title so that it'll describe the question more accurately.*

**Update** - apparently, the name is chord diagram.

Comment: The name you were looking for is chord diagram. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r

Comment: Chord diagram with barplots?