# Control colors of links based on source and target nodes in edgebundleR

Tags: r, chord, chord-diagram, circos

This question can be considered to be an extension of [Network chord diagram woes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r/35233319#35233319)

Is it possible to change the colors of the links in the plot based on whether the node on which the cursor is set is a source node or a target node as done in the following example?
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999

I don’t intend to make the question more verbose by giving a reproducible example as the codes are already available in the links. Any help would be great.