# D3tree, Changing colour by group

Tags: r

and happy new year.

I am now analysing text and want to visualise them with R.
I made a graph very successful but I cannot find a way to change the colour by a group.

in the graph I attached.. as you can see there are 6 different groups( I know most of you doesnt know korea. but anyway in the center of the graph tehre is one word and it made 6 different lines and each 6 words have other words.)

[tree_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMo8j.png)
what I want to do is.. 
Six of groups should have different nodes colour.
and want to change words colur with black.

how can I make it?

thanks in advance...

and this is my code (?)

```
d3Tree(List = 백남준, fontsize = 10, diameter = 500,file ="text.html")
```

Comment: changing the text to black is straight forward just add ``textColour='black'``, however I'm not sure that the d3Tree function has the flexibility to color by group. Usually more flexibility means more complexity.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the other options out there like 

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/collapsibleTree/versions/0.1.7  .

Or maybe this ggraph example :

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/339-circular-dendrogram-with-ggraph/ .

This question might also help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r