# Network chord diagram / hierarchical edge bundle in R

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

I tried to use the package "edgebundleR" to create the hierarchical edge bundle plot.
I can successfully produce the plot using the sample code from
[edgebundleR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgebundleR/README.html)

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
d <- structure(list(ID = c("KP1009", "GP3040", "KP1757", "GP2243",
                           "KP682", "KP1789", "KP1933", "KP1662", "KP1718", "GP3339", "GP4007",
                           "GP3398", "GP6720", "KP808", "KP1154", "KP748", "GP4263", "GP1132",
                           "GP5881", "GP6291", "KP1004", "KP1998", "GP4123", "GP5930", "KP1070",
                           "KP905", "KP579", "KP1100", "KP587", "GP913", "GP4864", "KP1513",
                           "GP5979", "KP730", "KP1412", "KP615", "KP1315", "KP993", "GP1521",
                           "KP1034", "KP651", "GP2876", "GP4715", "GP5056", "GP555", "GP408",
                           "GP4217", "GP641"),
                    Type = c("B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B",
                             "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                             "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A",
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                             "A", "A"),
                    Set = c(15L, 1L, 10L, 21L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 16L,
                            19L, 22L, 3L, 12L, 22L, 15L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 12L, 3L, 10L, 8L,
                            8L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 25L, 15L, 6L, 21L, 9L, 5L, 24L, 9L, 20L, 5L,
                            2L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 10L, 21L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 11L),
                    Loc = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L,
                            1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L,
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L,
                            1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)),
               .Names = c("ID", "Type", "Set", "Loc"), class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -48L))
# let's add Loc to our ID
d$key <- d$ID
d$ID <- paste0(d$Loc,".",d$ID)
# Get vertex relationships
sets <- unique(d$Set[duplicated(d$Set)])
rel <-  vector("list", length(sets))
for (i in 1:length(sets)) {
  rel[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(combn(subset(d, d$Set ==sets[i])$ID, 2)))
}
rel <- rbindlist(rel)
# Get the graph
g <- graph.data.frame(rel, directed=F, vertices=d)
clr <- as.factor(V(g)$Loc)
levels(clr) <- c("salmon", "wheat", "lightskyblue")
V(g)$color <- as.character(clr)
V(g)$size = degree(g)*5
# igraph static plot
# plot(g, layout = layout.circle, vertex.label=NA)

eb<-edgebundle( g )
```

However, I want my plot like [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling).
All the edges are colored with grey, and outgoing edges are colored with red and ingoing edges are colored with blue when the mouse hover the node. (I still want my node colored with the LOC.)

Based on the post [Network chord diagram woes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r/32260962#32260962).
I added the code

```
eb <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  eb,
'
function(el,x){
  x.edges.map(function(edge){
    var source = edge.from.split(".")[1];
    var target = edge.to.split(".")[1];
    d3.select(el).select(".link.source-" + source )
      .style("stroke","#f00");
    d3.select(el).select(".target-" + target)
      .style("stroke","#00f");
  })
}
'
)
eb
```

but it doesnt work, I know nothing about java script. I'm wondering what else should I modify the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may have been some changes to the package since that answer was posted. I'll provide an alternative means of accomplishing the result using javascript as it appears that options with pure R are limited in this case.

We can select the links and the nodes within our onRender javascript with:

```
  // select all the links:
  var links = d3.select(el).selectAll(".link");
  
  // select all the nodes:
  var nodes = d3.select(el).selectAll(".node")
```

We then assign an event listener to the nodes that will color links that connect to it:

```
  // set up an event listener on the nodes:
  nodes.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // color matching links:
    d3.select(el).selectAll(".source-"+d.key)
      .style("stroke","steelblue")
      
    d3.select(el).d3.selectAll(".target-"+d.key)
      .style("stroke","crimson");
  })
```

*I don't need to select `el` first, but if there are multiple charts on the same page I prevent selecting the wrong ones.*

Now I need to also add an event listener to revert the color on mouseout:

nodes.on("mouseout", function() {
links.style("stroke","#555");
})

Together I have:

```
library(edgebundleR)
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
d <- structure(list(ID = c("KP1009", "GP3040", "KP1757", "GP2243",
                           "KP682", "KP1789", "KP1933", "KP1662", "KP1718", "GP3339", "GP4007",
                           "GP3398", "GP6720", "KP808", "KP1154", "KP748", "GP4263", "GP1132",
                           "GP5881", "GP6291", "KP1004", "KP1998", "GP4123", "GP5930", "KP1070",
                           "KP905", "KP579", "KP1100", "KP587", "GP913", "GP4864", "KP1513",
                           "GP5979", "KP730", "KP1412", "KP615", "KP1315", "KP993", "GP1521",
                           "KP1034", "KP651", "GP2876", "GP4715", "GP5056", "GP555", "GP408",
                           "GP4217", "GP641"),
                    Type = c("B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B",
                             "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                             "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A",
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                             "A", "A"),
                    Set = c(15L, 1L, 10L, 21L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 16L,
                            19L, 22L, 3L, 12L, 22L, 15L, 25L, 10L, 25L, 12L, 3L, 10L, 8L,
                            8L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 25L, 15L, 6L, 21L, 9L, 5L, 24L, 9L, 20L, 5L,
                            2L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 10L, 21L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 11L),
                    Loc = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L,
                            1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L,
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L,
                            1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)),
               .Names = c("ID", "Type", "Set", "Loc"), class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA, -48L))
# let's add Loc to our ID
d$key <- d$ID
d$ID <- paste0(d$Loc,".",d$ID)
# Get vertex relationships
sets <- unique(d$Set[duplicated(d$Set)])
rel <-  vector("list", length(sets))
for (i in 1:length(sets)) {
  rel[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(combn(subset(d, d$Set ==sets[i])$ID, 2)))
}
rel <- rbindlist(rel)
# Get the graph
g <- graph.data.frame(rel, directed=F, vertices=d)
clr <- as.factor(V(g)$Loc)
#levels(clr) <- c("salmon", "wheat", "lightskyblue")
levels(clr) <- c("#555","#555","#555")
V(g)$color <- as.character(clr)
V(g)$size = degree(g)*5
# igraph static plot
# plot(g, layout = layout.circle, vertex.label=NA)

eb<-edgebundle( g )

eb <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  eb,
  '
function(el,x){

  // select all the links:
  var links = d3.select(el).selectAll(".link");
  
  // select all the nodes:
  var nodes = d3.select(el).selectAll(".node")
  
  // set up an event listener on the nodes:
  nodes.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // color matching links:
    d3.selectAll(".source-"+d.key)
      .style("stroke","steelblue")
      
    d3.selectAll(".target-"+d.key)
      .style("stroke","crimson");
  })
  
  nodes.on("mouseout", function() {
    links.style("stroke","#555");
  })
  
}
'
)
eb
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. However, when I colored my nodes with different color, all the edge will be the same color as the nodes first. After the mouse hovered the node, all the edge will turn grey. I'm wondering if its possible that I do not need the step "hover the node" to make all edge grey when nodes are in different color. Sorry its really hard to explain my question.