# R Circlize Chord Diagram Output

Tags: r

I am new to the circlize package in R. However, the output from my first chord diagram looks oval-shaped rather than a circle as shown in the documentation examples. What can I do? Code and image below.

```
    #random matrix, for illustration
    mat
       E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6
    S1  8 13 18  6 11 14
    S2 10 12  1  3  5  7
    S3  2 16  4 17  9 15
    chordDiagram(mat)
```

**This is my output :**

[image: This is my output]

**This is what I want :**

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: There are also [other choord diagram options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37358145/5977215)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to force a squared plotting region using [`par(pty="s")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) :

```
library(circlize)

mat <- read.table(text=
",E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6
S1,8,13,18,6,11,14
S2,10,12,1,3,5,7
S3,2,16,4,17,9,15",header=TRUE,sep=",",row.names=1)
par(pty="s")
chordDiagram(as.matrix(mat))
```

[image: diagram]